# Pasar una cadena a ascii en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estaba realizando un código donde debo ingresar un texto que contenga letras y números. Ingresar un valor y desplazar el valor ASCII en esa cantidad de cada carácter del texto para así codificarlo.
El problema esta en que no me muestra la cadena con las letras en mayusculas.

Ejemplo:

texto = “Hoy es Viernes 15 de Octubre”.

numero = 1

Resultado: "Ipz!ft!Wjfsoft!26!ef!Pduvcsf"

```
def codificado(texto,desplazamiento):
    abecedario = ''' !"#$%&☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼'©)*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⌂ÇüéâäàåçêëèîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜø£×ƒáíóúñÑªº¿®¬½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤ÁÀ©╣║╗╚¢¥┐└┴┬├─┼ãÃ╩╔╩'''
    cadena_aux = ''
    for x in range( len(texto) ):
        for y in range(len(abecedario)):
            desplazamiento_abc = y + desplazamiento

            if desplazamiento_abc >= len( abecedario ):
                desplazamiento_abc -= len( abecedario )

            if texto[x] == abecedario[y]:
                cadena_aux += abecedario[ desplazamiento_abc ]
    return(cadena_aux)

texto= str(input())

desplazamiento = int(input())

while desplazamiento>27:
    desplazamiento = int(input())

texto=texto.lower()

print(codificado(texto,desplazamiento))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nótese que estás usando:

`texto=texto.lower()`

Por lo que todo el proceso se realiza en minúsculas, no hay mayúsculas cuando se llama a la función *codificado()*. Debes eliminar esa línea de código si quieres conservar las mayúsculas.

Comment: Si tenes razon pero creo que esta mal la tabla de caracteres porque me tendria que salir con las comillas la palabra

Comment: Si quieres incluir comillas, debes ponerlas "dentro" de otras comillas distintas, por ejemplo `'`, siendo así: `texto = '"Hoy es Viernes 15 de Octubre"'`